# One word for (have same size)

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that expresses "same size" characteristic. To be specific, we can say that *"both DVD's are **identical**"*. However, "identical" might imply all characteristics resemblance. I am looking for a word that emphasizes the size resemblance only. Is there such a word?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are words like *congruent, isomorphic and isometric* that can mean having same size, form, dimensions etc. but they are technical terms and they don't fit your context.

*Congruent* is used in geometry and *isomorphic* is used in chemistry and biology mainly.

In my opinion, your best bet is saying **equal in size**.

If one really needs a single word, there is a self-explanatory word that means exactly equal in size: *equisized*. However, it is not a common word and it sounds rather humorous. It is mainly used in technical contexts if you search in [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=equisized&rlz=1C1VDKB_enCA994CA994&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwib_8Xqj8z4AhVRR_EDHSQfCFU4WhD8BSgBegQIARAL&biw=1536&bih=746&dpr=1.25).

> **equisized** 
> Of the same size. 
> *from The Century Dictionary and Cyclopedia* 
> [*wordnik.com*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/equisized)

Comment: Why not [*same-sized*](https://www.wordnik.com/words/same-sized)?

Comment: @bib

Interestingly, I couldn't find any dictionary entry for "same-sized". Though it is used both with hyphen and without hyphen. But I think, "equal in size" is a more common usage.

Comment: Yes, but a hyphenated neologism is not likely to get you in too much trouble. Some are obviously doing it.

Comment: "Both DVD's are *the same width*"

Answer (score 1):

What about **[equidimensional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidimensional)**?

> Equidimensional is an adjective applied to objects that have nearly the same size or spread in multiple directions. As a mathematical concept, it may be applied to objects that extend across any number of dimensions. More specifically, it's also used to characterize the shape of three-dimensional solids

Comment: Perfect selection, you have added to my vocabulary. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The first word that comes to mind is "congruent."

For DVDs and wheel-shaped things in general you might get away with the word equirotal but that's a bit more metaphorical than adjectives should be.

"Proportional" can be equal in size ("proportionally cubed cheese" for example) but does not always imply that.

Times, intervals and distances can be 'regular' even though their content varies, so long as they are equal in size or length.

The noun 'doublet' can imply things that are very similar but not identical "a doublet of disks."

The word "symmetrical" flirts with this meaning. A symmetry exists between the two DVDs, the houses are symmetrical, but even that still may convey other characteristic resemblance.

Comment: I like `'congruent'` because anyone who made it through high school geometry should know it means `"same size and shape"`. When you're speaking to those who didn't make it through high school geometry (or can't remember if they did) you'd probably want to fall back on `"same size and shape"`.

Answer (score -1):

"Commensurate" can mean having an corresponding suitability  (size,  weight, gravity (ie graveness or seriouesness)).  Such as: an answer commensurate with the difficulty of the question.

Dictionary says  "commensurate"  is: corresponding in size or degree; in proportion.

Answer (score -1):

Surprised that nobody mentioned "uniform."

For the particular situation I'm puzzling over, it sprang to mind immediately, but yet something didn't seem quite perfect enough, and I wound up here.

As in many things, I think my first instinct was the best suited. So thanks to all for their ideas presented on this page, since they helped me avoid belaboring the choice.